# How to run AutoHotKey script as an admin every time a user logs in?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, scheduled-tasks

I have computers where quite a few users log in. I want to restrict the usage to a maximum of 12 hours after which an ahk script logs off the user. I have the following solution but couldn't figure out the last part of it:

1. Convert ahk script to exe.
2. Launch the exe as a scheduled task at user logon 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427673/how-to-run-a-program-automatically-as-admin-on-windows-startup

Joshua Frank's answer to a different [question](https://superuser.com/questions/478052/windows-7-task-scheduler-hidden-setting-doesnt-work) provides solution by running the task as `system`. I am not able to understand how to run a scheduled task as `system`. I explored the options of scheduled task but the best I can do is to run it with the highest privileges (not to mention hidden).

On a side note, is there a simpler way to run an ahk script (preferably its compiled exe) every time a user logs in, so that unless he/she is the admin, the script cannot be terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type in SYSTEM as a user in the Task Scheduler:

[image: task scheduler 1]

Click "Change User or Group..." and type SYSTEM into the box.

[image: system object]

Make sure you set the task to trigger if any user logs in:

[image: triggers]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable AdminApprovalMode. This way you dont need to run as admin when you are admin.
http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/turn-off-admin-approval-mode-in-windows-7/