# Scheduled Tasks - Display the script

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks, robocopy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Windows 7 scheduled task running hidden?](https://superuser.com/questions/78359/why-is-windows-7-scheduled-task-running-hidden)

I have a couple of Robocopy scripts setup in a scheduled task, but is there a way to actually display the cmd prompt with progress then the task runs? Or will it always run silently in the background?

Cheers

Comment: What Windows Vesion?

Comment: 2008R2 SP1 (and some other text to fill minimum req.)

Comment: Take a look at [this Super User post](http://superuser.com/questions/78359/why-is-windows-7-scheduled-task-running-hidden). It is for Windows 7, but applies to server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How odd - it always shows for me.

My guess is that you have set up to run the task as a specific user (in task scheduler) which is not the same user as the one you are logged in as. Therefore it runs, but as it's on a different account, you don't see it (although it should appear in task manager if you check Show process form all users in the processes tab)!

Comment: It's set to run as my logged on user ! Strange...